# How to give Team Drive access to a Service Account without enabling Team Drive sharing with external parties?

Tags: google-drive-api

Th company I work for recently switched to using Team Drive and we had multiple applications that would interact with Google Drive using the Google Drive API. The API calls would be authorized using Google Service Accounts and access to specific files would be given to an app by sharing the file with the Service Account email in the same way you would share a file with a normal user. Now that we've switched to Team Drive I'm unable to grant access to the Service Account as the email address associated with it is not considered part of our organization. I've also looked into adding the Service Account as a normal user in our organization through the Google Admin dashboard, but it only allows me to create new users, not include existing ones. The only solution I've found is to enable sharing with external parties which would allow me to share Team Drive files with the Service Account, which would be considered an external party. This solution is risky and incorrect as the applications using the Service Account are part of our organization. We also do not want enable sharing with external parties in general for security reasons.

I've followed the steps described in [How to access Team Drive using service account with Google Drive .NET API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243865/how-to-access-team-drive-using-service-account-with-google-drive-net-api-v3) and they work, but as mentioned above they require sharing with external parties to be enabled which we do not want.

The ideal solution would be for the Service Account to be considered part of our organization, but I cannot find a way to do this.

I've also tried delegating Domain-Wide Authority to the Service Account as described in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority, but as far as I understand this is not what I want as this will allow the Service Account to impersonate other users, but the reason we have a Service Account is for carrying out processes that happen automatically and which aren't associated with a specific user.

I've also followed the steps outlined here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account for white-listing a specific API service through the Google Admin Security interface, but this doesn't seem to do anything, and I'm not sure what it is supposed to do as I have already enabled the Drive API for this Service Account in the APIs & Services dashboard where I originally created the Service Account.

We're using R and so I've been using the [googledrive](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/reference/team_drives.html) package which has functions for working with Team Drives like:

```
googledrive::drive_find()
googledrive::team_drive_find()
googledrive::team_drive_get(id = "team-drive-id")
```

I would expect to be able to see the team drive, but I guess this is not possible unless the Service Account email is a member of the Team Drive which is not possible because the Service Account (which is linked to our organization through its owner) is not considered part of our organization.

Comment: Hey did you managed to do it? having the same problem

Comment: In the end we had to make a separate team drive for the files that we wanted to interact with using the API. Far from ideal, but it's a working solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and after trying a lot of approaches, landed on the solution below (++):

- Create a group in Google Workspace. You can add any external identity/email to a group, since they can be used for multiple things. So add the role account to this group.
- Google has recently come out with "Trust" rules, that allow granular sharing. You can share with a group. So I created a trust rule that allowed sharing of any data source (easier than restricting who can share since file/shared drive ownership affects this rule) to only the group that contains the service account. Now external sharing is permitted, but only to the role account.
- Lastly, share the drive with that role account.

++ Note that I also had followed the majority of steps above including the GCP project creation and domain-wide delegation before this portion, but was similarly stuck getting a 403 for access rights.